# Ajax $.ajax is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery AJAX call that does this:

```
function testIndustry() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "URL INSERTED HERE",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(dataJsonP) {
            if (dataJsonP.industry.indexOf('Manufacturing') >= 0){
                //do something
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But I keep getting this error

> TypeError: $.ajax is not a function (in function testIndustry, line 6, col 5)

I read up on StackOverflow and seems like that usually happens when  AJAX function is called like this

```
$.ajax()({});
```

with an extra pair of opening and closing brackets, which I am not using. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the `$` variable has been overwritten by another library and no longer references jQuery. As a short term fix, try using `jQuery.ajax` to fix the issue. You may want to research on `noConflict()` if it does solve the problem. You should also remove `async: false` as it's terrible practice to use it.

Comment: Thanks Rory for suggesting both Short term fix and no conflict. I'll look into it.

Comment: jsonp doesn't accept some of the options you are using .

Comment: The thing with `$.ajax()({});` would result in a different error saying `$.ajax(…)` wasn’t a function. `$.ajax` and `$.ajax(…)` are not the same thing.

Comment: Related: [TypeError: $.ajax is not a function while running a ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38090698/4642212).