# TypeError: $.ajax is not a function while running a ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

Instead of curl, I'm using jsonp format to extract data from the api. Here I'm using wit.ai api for sample reference. I have made a request using the following format.

Sample Curl to get this

```
$ curl \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN' \
      'https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160526&q=hello'
```

And now my code

```
var $ = require('jquery');

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.wit.ai/message',
  data: {
    'q': 'set an alarm in 10min',
    'access_token' : 'MY_WIT_TOKEN'
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
      console.log("success!", response);
  }
});
```

And then I executed node app.js in the terminal which gave the following error.

```
c:\app.js:3
$.ajax({
  ^

TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\app.js:3:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Why I'm getting the error? Is there any other way to run ajax using the terminal?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that jQuery was not successfully loaded due to some reasons or others.

Comment: Related: [Ajax $.ajax is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35229699/4642212).

Comment: could it be that `require()` is case sensitive? so maybe try with this instead `require('jQuery')` ? note: I have no idea whether i'm right or not

Comment: @Guillaume no it didnt worked

Comment: check this jquery in Browsers source tab that, it is loaded or not

Comment: @NitinDhomse same error with even jquery included

Comment: I think require() is to load PHP files. why you can't use                       <script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: it's odd that you are using jquery for server side script. It's meant to be used in client side only.

Comment: @kasperite  Worked in browser,but is there way to get the json in terminal

Comment: surely works in browser if you execute $.ajax in DOM context but not in terminal though

Comment: @NitinDhomse he's using node. Require is a javascript package - http://requirejs.org/ - and he cant use `script src` because thats html and not javascript

Comment: this might be of some use - http://quaintous.com/2015/07/31/jqery-node-mystery/

Comment: I think you'd be better off using something like basic `http` requests. This article - https://davidwalsh.name/nodejs-http-request - gives you an idea of how to do it or use a module created to do such a thing like https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery on the client side, include this in the `<head>` tag of your template:

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you are using jquery on the server side, install jquery using npm, and use this:

```
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
```

Personally I will not prefer using jquery on the client side.

Comment: So even though jquery is written, and much of it only makes sense on the client side, you prefer to use it on the server side, or do you just have a problem with jquery?

Comment: I just prefer to use it on server side.